# Adding a string column to matrix in a csv file MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, csv

I have a matrix A of dimension say this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I have a vector

```
c1 c2 c3
```

I want this new matrix to be written to a file

```
c1 c2 c3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

How can I do this? I looked everyhwere I thought but get issues with the string and numbers...

Comment: Please see: [mcve]. What are `c1`, `c2` and `c3`? Variables? Strings? Since you looked everywhere, what have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: I can create the new cell but not write it to a file.